# New to GitHub: Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged, and have 1 and 2 different commits each, respectively. What should I do?

Tags: git, github, merge, branch

I'm pretty new to GitHub (I stick to add, commit, and push and haven't played around with new branches) and today was trying to push some changes. However, I committed some files and realized I messed something up and tried to uncommit by running:

```
git reset --mixed HEAD~;
```

I tried pushing and resetting a few more times. I'm not exactly sure what I did, but I ended up here when checking git status:

```
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 1 and 2 different commits each, respectively.
```

When I try to push, it states:

```
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

So I think I'm now behind quite a bit because there are some files that have been tracked for the last two commits or so that git status is now saying are untracked. Furthermore, I don't want to lose any of my progress that I've made locally on my computer. How can I fast forward and push the changes I'd like to make, ideally without losing any past commits or current progress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I think I'm now behind quite a bit because there are some files that have been tracked for the last two commits or so that git status is now saying are untracked. Furthermore, I don't want to lose any of my progress that I've made locally on my computer. How can I fast forward and push the changes I'd like to make, ideally without losing any past commits or current progress?

Let's separate these into their various components, so that you can properly understand what's going on.  The components we care about here are:

- Repositories: you have one on your computer, and GitHub has one on theirs.
- Inside each repository:

  - commits
  - branch names

The commits literally get shared, while the branch names do not—they're handled in a fancier way.  But the commits only get shared at specific *connection points*, when you have your Git call up the Git over at GitHub; your Git and their Git then have a little conversation about these branch names and the commits.  Let's leave that for later, and concentrate on what's in *your* Git repository first: the commits, and the names.

#### Names

Usually I start with the commits first, but this time, let's start with just the names.  There are more kinds of names than just *branch* names and we'll come back to that later, but for now, let's just worry about what a branch name is and does.

A branch name is just a name—a series of letters, preferably, and/or digits, with some rules that prevent you from using things like `br..an..ch` as a branch name but allow `bra.nch`.  This branch name's main function is to hold *one* commit hash ID.  This is the hash ID of the *latest* commit.  So without the *commits*, names don't actually do you any good at all.

#### Commits

Commits are the real central feature of Git.  Almost everything is about the commits.  Commits save versions of your files, forever—or for at least as long as those commits continue to exist—but it's important to understand *how* a commit does this, and how Git *finds* a commit.

Let's start this part with a simple idea: every commit is numbered.  The numbers, however, aren't simple counting numbers.  They're not commits 1, 2, and 3.  Instead, each number is a big ugly *hash ID*.  It *looks* totally random (though in fact it's entirely non-random).  There's no obvious connection from the latest commit, whose number is, say, `4a0fcf9f760c9774be77f51e1e88a7499b53d2e2`, to its previous commit.

To *find* a commit, you need to know its number.  But the numbers look random, and are too big and ugly for humans to remember.  That's why we have the branch names: they remember the number of the *last* commit.  But wait: what good is it to know only the *last* commit?  Well, let's take a look at what's inside each commit.

Every commit has two parts: it has its data, which is a full snapshot of *all* of your files.  We'll come back to this in a moment.  Then it has some *metadata*, or information about the commit itself.  In this metadata you will find the name of the person who made the commit, *when* they made the commit, and *why* they made the commit: their log message.  But Git will also store, and find, one more piece of information that Git itself wants, and that is the number—the hash ID—of this commit's *parent* commit.

The parent of any commit is the commit that comes *before* that commit.  So for ordinary single-parent commits—which tends to be most of them—this means that Git can start from the *last* commit and simply work backwards.  That's exactly what Git does, and we can draw it like this:

```
A <-B <-C   <--master
```

Here we have a simple repository with just three commits in it, all on one branch named `master`.  The *name* `master` holds the hash ID of the last commit—which we're calling `C` even though it has some big ugly hash ID—and that commit `C` holds the hash ID of earlier commit `B`.  So Git can use the *name* to find `C`, and then use `C` to find `B`.

Meanwhile `B` holds the hash ID of earlier commit `A`, so having found `B`, Git can find `A`.  `A` is the very first commit anyone ever made, so it just has no parent.  That lets Git stop working backwards.

#### Commits and branches

There's one more interesting wrinkle here, which occurs once we have more than one branch.  Let's say we're up to eight commits in our repository:

```
...--G--H   <-- master
```

I've stopped bothering drawing in the backwards arrows between commits.  That's OK because all commits necessarily point backwards, and there's one other key thing about commits: *once you make a commit, nothing in it can ever change.*<sup>1</sup>  So the backwards-pointing arrow is frozen and there is no way to add a forwards-pointing arrow.  That's not the case for the *branch names*, though: remember, `master` used to contain the real hash ID of commit `C`; now it contains the actual hash ID of commit `H`.

If we make a *new* branch name now, the new name will *also point to commit `H`.*<sup>2</sup>  Let's draw that:

```
...--G--H   <-- develop, master
```

Which name are we actually using?  Git has an answer for us: we should attach the special name `HEAD`, written in all uppercase like this,<sup>3</sup> to the branch we want to be using.  So:

```
...--G--H   <-- develop, master (HEAD)
```

means *we are using the name `master`, which selects commit `H`*, while:

```
...--G--H   <-- develop (HEAD), master
```

means *we are using the name `develop`, which selects commit `H`*.

---

<sup>1</sup>The reason it's frozen like this is that the commit's number—its hash ID—is built by computing a secure hash of all of the bits in the data and metadata.  This means that it's literally impossible to change a commit.  If you take one out, turn it into ordinary data, change a bit, and write it back, you get a *new and different commit*.  The original commit remains in the repository; you've merely added a new, different commit.

<sup>2</sup>Actually, we can pick *any* existing commit to make the name.  We *must* pick some existing commit, though: you are not allowed to have a branch name that doesn't point to some existing commit.

<sup>3</sup>On some systems, you can type `head` in lowercase and have it work.  This is a bad habit to get into because:

- it does not work on *all* systems, and
- it breaks when you start using `git worktree`.

If you don't like typing out the word `HEAD`, consider using the one-character synonym `@`.

---

#### Making new commits, part 1

One place where `HEAD` matters a lot is when we go to make a *new* commit.  Suppose we have:

```
...--G--H   <-- develop (HEAD), master
```

Either way we're *using* commit `H`.  But if we change some files and `git add` them and `git commit`, this tells Git to make a *new* commit.  Let's call the new commit `I` and draw it in, like this:

```
...--G--H
         \
          I
```

Note that the *parent* of new commit `I` is existing commit `H`.  That's because we started from commit `H`.

What happens to the *branch names?*  The answer is: Git *automatically updates the name to which `HEAD` is attached*.  Since `HEAD` was and still is attached to `develop`, that's the name that now points to new commit `I`:

```
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

If we now `git checkout master` to go back to `master`, Git will return us to existing commit `H`, attach the special name `HEAD` to `master`, and give us:

```
...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
         \
          I   <-- develop
```

#### Commits are read-only, so how do files work?

We mentioned earlier that commits are frozen-in-time snapshots of *all* of your files.  To make this work well, Git stores each file in a special, read-only, Git-only, frozen and de-duplicated format.  Only Git itself can *use* these files.  So when we pick some commit to use, Git *copies the files out of the commit* into a work area.  That work area, with ordinary everyday files in it, is your *work-tree* or *working tree*.

The de-duplication means that even though each commit has a full snapshot of *every* file, most of those snapshots are simply re-using existing files.  That is, when we made commit `I`, we probably changed one or two files, and left all the others the same.  So commit `I` and commit `H` actually *share* most of their files.  They probably share most of *those* with earlier commits, too, up to some point.  (In fact, if you change a file *back* to the way it was in some earlier commit, the new file is automatically shared with the older commit.)

That's the data inside each commit: a full, frozen snapshot of *all* of your files—or rather, of all the files you told Git to put into that snapshot.  So which files are those?

#### Making new commits, part 2

Each commit holds these frozen-format files, which need to be expanded out into your work-tree.  You might assume, then, that `git commit` takes whatever is in your work-tree and commits it.  But that's not in fact how Git works.

Besides the original, in-commit, frozen files, and the in-work-tree, everyday files, Git keeps an *intermediate copy* of each file.<sup>4</sup>  This extra copy is in an area that is either so important, or so badly named originally, that it has three names.  Git calls it the *index*, or the *staging area*, or sometimes—rarely these days—the *cache*.  I'll use the term *index* here but remember that *staging* refers to these extra copies.

The index copy of each file is in the frozen *format*, ready to go into the next commit.  So this means that a good way to think of Git's index is that it contains the *proposed next commit*.  The `git add` command tells Git: *copy the work-tree, ordinary format copy of the file into, or back into, the index, replacing any previous copy.*  This also prepares it in the frozen format (de-duplicating it too) so that it's ready for the next `git commit`.

When you do run `git commit`, Git gathers any extra information it needs for the metadata—such as your name and log message—and then builds a new commit.  Then it writes out whatever is in the index *right then* as the snapshot, adds the metadata—including the current commit as the new commit's parent—and makes the new commit, and then updates whichever branch name `HEAD` is attached to.

If you like to use `git commit -a`, be aware that this just makes `git commit` update files that are *already there in the index*.  It's very nearly equivalent to running `git add -u` (update known files) followed by `git commit`.<sup>5</sup>

You can't see the index directly,<sup>6</sup> but `git status` tells you, implicitly, what's in the index.  The way `git status` works is also pretty simple:

- You have a *current commit*.  That's the one that your branch name (found by looking at `HEAD`) says is the *last* commit.  That commit has a bunch of files in it, in Git's special, internal, frozen format.  Git also calls this the `HEAD` commit.
- Git has its index.  That has a bunch of files in it, in Git's special frozen format—but unlike the ones in the commit, they can be *replaced* with new copies.
- And, you have your work-tree, where you can do anything you want—including create all-new files.

The `git status` command does two separate comparisons:

- First, it compares all the files in the `HEAD` commit to all the files in the index.  For every file that is *the same*, it says nothing at all.  For every file that is *different*—including new or gone—it says that this file is *staged for commit*.
- Then `git status` compares all the files in Git's index to the files in your work-tree.  For every file that is *the same* (after expanding out of frozen form), it says nothing at all.  For every file that is *different*, it says that this file is *not staged for commit*.

This means you can view what *can be updated* in the index, without having to view every file in the index that's the *same* as the copies in the

---

<sup>4</sup>Technically, what's in the index is not a *copy* of the file, but rather a *reference* to a frozen-format Git internal *blob object*.  But you don't normally need to know this—it only matters if you start using `git ls-files --stage` and `git update-index` to work with Git's low-level index.

<sup>5</sup>The main difference here is that if making the new commit *fails*, the `git commit -a` method rolls the index back.  Using `git add -u` is a separate step, so if the add works and the commit fails, the index is still updated.  There are a bunch of more-subtle distinctions too, but we'll ignore all the tricky corner cases here.  The important point is that Git makes commits from an index, and usually there's only one index—*the* index—and everything else flows from that.

<sup>6</sup>Actually, you *can* see what's in the index: run `git ls-files --stage`.  Note that this dumps a lot of output in a big repository!  This command is not one you'd normally use: it's meant for Git programs to use internally, not for users.

---

#### Tracked and untracked files

Now that you know that Git makes its commits from its index, you can finally understand tracked and untracked files correctly.  The definition of a *tracked file* is wonderfully simple, yet still complicated: **A tracked file is one that is in Git's index right now.**

You can add files to the index at any time: `git add newfile`.  That file is now tracked.  You can *remove* files from the index any time, too: `git rm --cached oldfile`.  The `--cached` prevents `git rm` from removing your work-tree copy, so that you can still *see* the file, but it's no longer in Git's index: that file is now untracked.

But remember: `git checkout branch` tells Git to *fill its index and your work-tree* from some existing commit!  So Git will update its index on its own.  If there are files right now in Git's index and your work-tree, and you `git checkout` a commit that *doesn't* have those files, Git will *remove* those files from its index and your work-tree, so that you'll see what is saved in that commit.

An *untracked file* is any file that is in your work-tree, but not in Git's index.  When you have such a file—one not in Git's index—and `git checkout` some other commit that also doesn't have that file, that file continues not to be in Git's index, and hence continues to be untracked.

(A sneaky case here occurs when you have an untracked file, then ask to switch to some commit that *does* have that file.  We won't worry about that here, but you can probably see how this can be a problem.)

#### Getting rid of commits

Commits are actually very hard to get rid of (short of removing the entire `.git` directory, which loses *everything* and is rarely a good idea).  That's because Git is built to *add new commits*, not to drop them.  But you can in fact get rid of commits.

Suppose some branch name and some series of commits:

```
...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
```

Now suppose further that we could convince Git that the *name* `master` should hold, not the hash ID of commit `H`, but that of commit `G` instead, like this:

```
       H
      /
...--G   <-- master (HEAD)
```

Note that commit `H` is actually still there, in the repository.  But Git *shows* us commits by starting from the commit whose ID is stored in a *name*, like `master`.  The name now says *commit `G` is the latest commit*.  Commit `G` points back to some earlier commit (`F`, probably).  So if we ask Git about the commits in this repository, we won't *see* commit `H` any more.

(We can, when we draw these, push the "discarded" commits up or down to get them out of the way.  I'm a bit limited by StackOverflow text conventions, but if you draw these on paper or a whiteboard, feel free to draw them any which way, including long swoopy arrows from branch names to commits.)

Note that this only works for "tail" commits.  That is, suppose we have:

```
...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
         \
          I   <-- develop
```

If we force the name `master` to point to commit `G`, well, commit `I` still points to commit `H`, so what we get is this:

```
...--G   <-- master (HEAD)
      \
       H--I   <-- develop
```

That is, now it looks like we made commit `H` on branch `develop`.  Still, branch `master` now ends at commit `G`, so we've definitely done *something*.

This is what `git reset` does.  When you ran:

> `git reset --mixed HEAD~`

you told your Git: *Find the commit that's one step back from `HEAD`—one back from the last commit on the current branch.  Then, force the current branch name to identify that commit.*  If you had:

```
...--G--H--I   <-- master
```

and you do this once, you end up with:

```
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I
```

If you do it again, the name `master` points to commit `G`, and `H-I` are left dangling.  In your repository, they'll stick around for a while, by default—user repositories get at least 30 days to get these commits back.  (The mechanism here is something Git calls *reflogs*, but we won't go into details.)

The `--mixed` argument to `git reset` tells Git to *leave the work-tree untouched* while moving things around.  So the copies of files that are in the work-tree are left alone.  With `--hard`, `git reset` adjusts those too.  With `--soft`, `git reset` leaves Git's index alone, but with `--mixed`, Git empties out the old index and fills it in from the commit you select.

This—replacing the index, but leaving the work-tree alone—can easily lead to the untracked-files case.  In particular, suppose commit `I` added a *new* file that is not in commit `H`.  Then the `reset` above removes the new file from Git's index, leaving the new file in your work-tree.  This file is now in your work-tree, but not in Git's index, and that is the very definition of an untracked file.

**Keep in mind that all the *committed* files are safe in those commits, as long as you can still *find* those commits.**  By making a commit like commit `I` hard to find, you've set things up so that you might not be able to get *those* versions of your files back easily.  But any commits that `git log` shows you, well, *those* commits are easy to find.  (We've skipped over the idea of using Git's *detached HEAD* mode to look at a historic commit, so as to not have to cover that mode, but that's one way to see historic versions.)

#### Add more Git repositories

Now that you know how commits, and branch names, in *your* repository work—including adding new commits, and resetting some commits away—it's time to add the GitHub Git into the mix.

For your Git to call up some other Git, you need to have a URL—something like `ssh://git@github.com/...` or `https://github.com/...`.  Your Git will *save* this URL for you, under a nice short memorable name.  Git calls this a *remote*.  Many Git repositories have only one remote, called `origin`, and I will assume that's the case for yours too.

To have your Git connect with this other Git, you will run one of three commands: `git fetch`, `git push`, and `git pull`.  The `git pull` command is just a convenience wrapper that runs `git fetch` first, then a second Git command, and it's best—well, *I* think it's best—to learn `git fetch` separately.  So that gives us just two commands that make Gits talk to each other.

The two commands on their own are relatively simple:

- `git fetch` has your Git call up their Git, and then ask them what they have, that you don't.  They list out their branch names (and other names) and their commit hash IDs.  Your Git can immediately tell whether you have these commits, because the hash IDs are the same in *every* Git repository (see footnote 1 again).  If you don't have the commits, your Git asks their Git to send them over.  They do, and now you have the commits too.

  Now that you have all the commits that they have (plus any of your own that you have not shared), your Git creates or updates your `origin/*` names, to *remember* what they have as *their* branch names.  Each of your `origin/*` names is a *remote-tracking name*.<sup>7</sup>  These are just your Git's memory of what hash IDs they had in which branch names, at the time you ran `git fetch`.

  If they don't *change* their branch names (ever, or often), your `git fetch` will set your remote-tracking names correctly every time.  If they do change them fairly often, you need to run `git fetch` fairly often to pick up any new names and different commit hash IDs.

  You can run `git fetch` just like this, with no arguments at all.
- `git push` has your Git call up their Git and then *give them new commits* if needed.  This is a little bit more complicated than `git fetch`, because for them to *remember* any new commits, they will have to update *their* branch names!  They do not have the equivalent of remote-tracking names for you.

  As with `git fetch`, your Git lists out commit hash IDs.  They check to see if they have those IDs.  If not, they have your Git send over those commits (and their files if necessary—there's a lot of fancy stuff in here to avoid sending files they already have copies of).  As before, the fact that every Git uses the *same* hash IDs for identical commits makes this easy.

  Then, once their Git has any commits required, your Git sends over one or more requests: *Please, if it's OK, set your branch name ______ (fill in a name) to ______ (fill in a hash ID)*.  It's up to them whether to obey this polite request.  Or, your Git can can send over a command: *Set your name _____ to _____!*  It's still up to them whether to obey.

  The `git push` command requires<sup>8</sup> that you put in the name `origin`, because long ago, someone said that the syntax was going to be `git push remote branch` so you have to put the `origin` in there before you put in the branch name.  Then, `git push` needs the name of the branch.  This tells your Git which commit(s) to send—your Git finds the *last* commit from your branch name as usual—and fills in the two blanks.  That is, we have to put both the branch name *and* the hash ID into the two blanks, for the polite request or forceful command.  Your Git gets both of these from the name you put in here.<sup>9</sup>

  They tell our Git whether they obeyed the command.  If so, our Git updates our one remote-tracking name corresponding to their branch name.  That is, if we got them to update their `master`, our Git updates our memory stored in `origin/master`.  Since we didn't find out any of their *other* branch names, none of our other `origin/*` names get updated.

---

<sup>7</sup>Git calls these things *remote-tracking branch names*, but I find that the word *branch* here makes things more confusing, not less; so now I leave it out and just call them *remote-tracking names*.

<sup>8</sup>You *can* set things up so that `git push` defaults to *push the current branch*, and then you can leave this out—Git will figure out both the right remote and the current branch—but I like to show the explicit version.

<sup>9</sup>There are additional options available so that you can get fancier.  For instance, you can push from your name `grandpa-simpson` to their name [`onion-on-my-belt`](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSimpsons/comments/7zpo19/so_i_tied_an_onion_to_my_belt_which_was_the_style/) if you like.  It's possible to use totally different names on each side.  But don't do that without a strong need: it rapidly becomes very confusing.

---

#### Fast-forwards and non-fast-forwards

Let's imagine, now, that we're a Git that is receiving a `git push`.  Some other Git has called us up and asked us if we have commit `a123456`.  We don't, so they gave it to us.  `a123456` has parent `9876543`, which we do have, so that's the only commit we need.  Now they say: *Please, if it's OK, set your `master` to `a123456`.*

Let's draw what we have:

```
...--G--H   <-- master
```

Suppose the hash ID of commit `H` *is* `9876543`.  Then the new commit `a123456` is apparently a new commit `I` that just *adds on to* our existing `master`, and we can put it in like this:

```
...--G--H--I   <-- master
```

But what if the parent, `9876543`, is *not* commit `H`?  What if it's commit `G`?  That is, we have:

```
...--G--H   <-- master
```

and they've given us:

```
...--G--H
      \
       I
```

and they are now asking us to set our `master` to remember commit `I`?  If we do that, we'll lose *our* commit `H`.  We will end up with:

```
       H
      /
...--G--I   <-- master
```

and we won't be able to find commit `H` any more.  So we'll say *no* to a polite request, because this operation doesn't just *add* commits to our `master`, it also *drops* a commit.

If they send us a forceful command—*set your `master` to `a123456`!*—we'll probably obey it, and drop commit `H`.  If *they* didn't keep a copy of commit `H`, it could go away pretty fast.  Server-side repositories often have no reflogs, and an abandoned / dangling commit can be removed almost immediately.

#### Your own situation

We can draw a picture of your situation, in which your `master` is `ahead 1, behind 2` of your `origin/master`—your Git's memory of *their* Git's `master`.  It might look like this:

```
          I--J   <-- origin/master
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K   <-- master (HEAD)
```

You can, if you like, use `git push --force origin master` to send them your commit `K` and tell them to *abandon* their `I-J` commits.  But if you want to keep those commits, don't do that.

You can, if you like, abandon your own commit `K`:

```
git reset [options] origin/master
```

will give you:

```
          I--J   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K   [abandoned]
```

Your commit `K` will stick around for a while, though finding it will be a bit hard.  If you don't want it after all, that's probably fine.

You can use `git merge` to combine the changes from commit `H` as compared to commit `K`, and the changes from commit `H` as compared to commit `J`, to make a new commit.  You can use `git rebase` to *copy* existing commit `K` to a new and different commit that adds on to commit `J`.  There are a lot of things you *can* do.  Each one has a different set of resulting commits.  Remember what a commit is and does for you, and how branch names find commits, and decide which commits you want, which ones you would like to pretend never happened—to remove with `git reset` and/or `git push --force`—and set things up in your own local repository the way you want.  Then use `git push`, with or without `--force`, to send new commits to the GitHub Git, and get them to set *their* branch names to point to the new commits, to match your own setup in *your* Git.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using git rebase. It's all cool stuff, can't wait to learn more about it as I keep using.